# methods/constructors and their return values

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, return-value

i'm new to programming and we just started learning "classes". I'm going to show you an example code which i found on the internet. My question is- Are **"add" and "res"** constructors and how is it possible that a constructor returns a value? **"X res and X add"** aren't int type methods and it still returns a value(there isn't also a variable for res), so i'm really confused.. I've saw in a few posts in stackoverflow that constructors can't return a value, but then what are **"X res and X add"** ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    X (int a=7, int b=6) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << a << b;
    }

    X add() {
        X res(a+b, a-b);
        return res;
    }

};

int main() {
    X x;
    x.add().print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are "add" and "res" constructors?

No. `add()` is a member function of class `X` and returns `X`, `res` is a local variable inside `add()` with type `X`.

> constructors can't return a value

Yes, it's right.

Comment: I think i got it.. And in the end i guess that the answer is something like - `x.print();` where `x` holds the values 13 and 1 and with the `print();` method we just print them out?

Answer (score 2):

> Are "add" and "res" constructors and how is it possible that a constructor returns a value?

No `add()` is a "normal" class member function, and it returns a new `X` instance called `res`, that was initialized using the `X(int, int)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> what are "X res and X add" ?

X res is means that res is an object of class X; add is the name of a member function of the class X, and  it can return an object of class X.

Answer (score 0):

> A class constructor is a special member function of a class that is
>   executed whenever we create new objects of that class.
>
> **A constructor will have exact same name as the class and it does not
>   have any return type at all, not even void.** Constructors can be very
>   useful for setting initial values for certain member variables.

So `add` and `print` not constructor. just `X (int a=7, int b=6) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }` is  constructor.